# Check if it is an integer

Tags: c++, string

I have the problem that I must read `Integers` from a database. The varibles are returned as `Strings` and can be `""`, `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"` or `"3"` (these are the ones I've seen so far). 
So using the standard `atoi` function doesn't help because then I can't differentiate between `""` and `"0"`.

Does somebody have a good solution to solve this?

Regards,
Stefan

**EDIT:**

"", "0", "1", "2" or "3" aren't the only possibilities I have seen so far... It is also possible that somebody writes "Hello World" in the field!!!

Comment: Check if the string is empty first.

Comment: @Kerrek: +1. There's only one special case here, that shouldn't be a tremendous burden to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is an issue in your case, I propose the followings:

**Solution 1:**

```
std::string input(<your string value>);
int val;
if (sscanf(input.c_str(), "%d", &val) != 1)
{
    cout << "it's empty/not an integer";
}
else
{
    cout << "val is:" << val;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
std::string input(<your string value>);
int val;
if(strcmp(input.c_str(), "") ==0)
{
    cout << "it's empty";
}
else
{
    val = atoi(input.c_str());
    cout << "val is:" << val;
}
```

I suggest to use the first solution because, if input starts invalid content(not an integer), the atoi solution fails (atoi returns 0 on fail).

Although, if you the values can be only "","0","1","2","3", the second solution should work too.

Answer (score 3):

Use `stringstream` to do the conversion:

```
int main()
{
    std::stringstream tmp;
    tmp << ""; //This would be the string from the database
    int x;
    if (tmp >> x)
    {
        //We won't get here
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
```

vs:

```
int main()
{
    std::stringstream tmp;
    tmp << "0";
    int x;
    if (tmp >> x)
    {
        //Will output 0
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
```

**EDIT:** This code *will* handle the case when someone inputs "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

The one condition is easy to check (`""`) because it will result as empty.

Secondly, you can remove the quotes doing something like

`std::string::find( '"' );`

will return `std::string::npos` if there are no double quotes in the string or the index of the first one.

`std::string::erase( pos, npos );`